# Materialize slider not working in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, materialize

I am developing a mvc webapp in asp.net, but my slider is not working. When I try the same code using html, it works. Here is my part of the code

```
<head>
 <link href="~/Content/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.slider').slider({ full_width: true });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>    
<div class="slider">
 <ul class="slides">
  <li>
   <img class="responsive-img" src="~/Content/img/hotel1.jpeg" /> 
  </li>
  <li>
   <img class="responsive-img" src="~/Content/img/hotel2.jpeg" /> 
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

When I check the code using Chrome developer tools it says

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function
```

and also

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ materialize.min.js:6
```

Comment: `$ is not defined` means jQuery is not initialized properly or doesn't exist on client-side. Check either if jQuery library exists, or use `<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js")">` to point with relative path.

Comment: Jquery ReferenceError is corrected. The problem is now with **slider**

Comment: Since your Materialize initialization code looks fine, try changing src attribute path value on second script tag with `"@Url.Content("~/Content/js/materialize.min.js")"`. Include jQuery UI library too if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with unwanted jquery and bootstrap reference. after I removed it from the file, It works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem are your script tags your script are supposed to be at the bottom of your page like this

```
<head>
 <link href="~/Content/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>    
<div class="slider">
 <ul class="slides">
  <li>
   <img class="responsive-img" src="~/Content/img/hotel1.jpeg" /> 
  </li>
  <li>
   <img class="responsive-img" src="~/Content/img/hotel2.jpeg" /> 
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.slider').slider({ full_width: true });
    });
</script>
</body>
```